# how to delete region with [delete] key in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23, dot-emacs

I am using Emacs 23.3 on Mac OS X Lion. How can I delete the selected text region with simple key typing—something like <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>C-d</kbd>? This works on windows without setting anything specific. How can I implement that in Mac OS X Lion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd>`cua-mode`. This will change a lot of things about the way Emacs behaves to fit the behavior of other GUI applications. For more information, see <kbd>M-S-:</kbd>`(info "(emacs) CUA Bindings")`.

You can turn it on persistently with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-option`<kbd>RET</kbd>`cua-mode`.

Answer (score 12):

You need to enable `delete-selection-mode` and then it will work ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you mean "delete between the mark and the cursor," the normal keybinding for this in Emacs is C-w (Hold down control and press w).

To set the mark, use C-SPC (hold down control and press SPACE).

Selecting a text region and then deleting it is not very common to normal Emacs users. More frequently they use

- C-k to delete entire lines at a time (or to the end of the current line)
- M-z (press Esc then z) to "zap to char" which will delete all text to the next occurrence of any character
- M-DEL (press Esc then DEL) to delete backwards a whole word at a time

and others.

Comment: thanks for you answer. but i want to bind [delete] key todo "delete-char" or "kill-region" in automatic.

Comment: i found the way to implements this function.

<pre>
(defun my-backward-delete-fun()
  "backward delete a char or delete selected region automic"
  (interactive)
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
      (call-interactively 'kill-region)
    (call-interactively 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
    )
  )
(global-set-key [backspace] 'my-backward-delete-fun)
</pre>

Comment: answer your own question, so you can help the next person who comes along!